# Problem installing IguanaTex on Mac (can't find `.dylib` file)

Tags: terminal, mac, ms-office, latex, dynamic-library

I'm trying to install an experimental version of [IguanaTex](https://github.com/ray851107/IguanaTexMac) on my Mac.  I'm stuck and need some help.

Here are the directions:

1. *install AppleScript (`IguanaTex.scpt`)*

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/Library/Application\ Scripts/com.microsoft.Powerpoint
   cp ./IguanaTex.scpt ~/Library/Application\ Scripts/com.microsoft.Powerpoint/IguanaTex.scpt
   ```

This worked fine for me.

2. install IguanaTexHelper (`libIguanaTexHelper.dylib`)

   ```
   sudo mkdir -p '/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Office365/User Content.localized/Add-Ins.localized'
   sudo cp ./libIguanaTexHelper.dylib '/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Office365/User Content.localized/Add-Ins.localized/libIguanaTexHelper.dylib'
   ```

**This is where I'm having an issue.** . I can't seem to find the file "`libIguanaTexHelper.dylib`" anywhere, and I can't find anything online about it.  I've already made sure that my computer is showing hidden files. 
 Can someone please help me clear this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the readme you are referring to, all the required files are on https://github.com/ray851107/IguanaTexMac/releases.

[image]